# How to make my own repository for ambari?

Tags: hadoop, repository, ambari

I'm new to apache ambari.

I'm trying to create cluster without HDP repository because Hortonworks repositories can't be accessed.(https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.6.0.0/bk_ambari-installation/content/hdp_26_repositories.html).

But I don't know how to make my own repository and what to be inside there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: It is not "for Ambari"; these are the repos that get added to all the Hadoop clients. If you've used Ubuntu for anytime, you might be familiar with PPA, or editing `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

It is just a regular APT/RPM repo which you can host with Sonatype Nexus or Artifactory.

For apt, you can use `apt-mirror` for cloning repos. For yum, then `createrepo` and `reposync` are two commands to manage repos.

Comment: Thank you. So that means once i have registered my own repository, ambari automatically install packages from my repo during hadoop provisioning?

Comment: It should, yes, if the packages arent available in the main OS repos